# Best method for using Entity Framework with web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, entity-framework-4

I have a legacy ASP.Net web application that is basically used to process web services.

I am adding some new functionality and would like to start using EF4.1.  I'm fairly new to EF, and I'm not quite sure the correct path to take here.

The client using this web service is a Linux based client running Apache, so data will be passed back and forth using SOAP.

My question is, what is the best practice for getting EF models into and out of a SOAP data class?  Would using EF POCO classes be the best for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the Entity Framework for data access with either a ASMX or WCF web service that will use SOAP.

[Using Entities with Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-14.aspx) show give you some direction and ideas.